# Any utility to print out array directly?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an array, I am wondering any utility to print out array directly?

Comment: Print to where? Pretty vague question!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use string's `Join()` method, like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("My array: {0}",
    string.Join(", ", myArray.Select(v => v.ToString()))
);
```

This will print array elements converted to `string`, separated by `", "`.

Comment: error when using the above code. the above code failed to compile

Comment: @AdamLee That's a typo: I put a curly brace at the end of the line instead of a regular one. It is now fixed. P.S. Downvoting over an easily spotted typo is not a good practice.

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer still cannot compile. The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @AdamLee I just verified that it compiles fine. Are you on .NET version prior to 4.0 by any chance? If you are on 3.x, try adding `ToArray()` at the end: `myArray.Select(v => v.ToString()).ToArray()`.

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight. I really on .Net 3.5. I tried with your solution. it is now works. Actually I like your solution more than the one provided by parapura, so I select your solution as the answer.

Comment: for Select, be sure to include a using statement for System.Linq. This will commonly be there when you create a class file in Visual Studio, but not necessarily in other IDEs/interfaces like sublime or .NET Fiddle.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following one liner to print an array

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 };

Array.ForEach( array , x => Console.WriteLine(x) );
```

Answer (score 3):

I like @dasblinkenlight solution, but I'd like to note that the select statement is not nessasary.

This code produces the same result for an array of strings:

```
string[] myArray = {"String 1", "String 2", "More strings"};
Console.WriteLine("My array: {0}", string.Join(", ", myArray));
```

I find it a little easier on the eyes having less code to read.

([linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net) is a fantastic app to test snippets of code like this.)

Comment: Good answer, but it depends on the version of the framework you're using and whether you want to be able to handle arrays of any type - only framework 4+ has the `string.Join(string, object[])` overload, so your method is limited to string arrays in earlier framework versions ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350.aspx))

Answer (score 2):

You can write an extension method something like this

```
namespace ConsoleApplication12
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var items = new []{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            items.PrintArray();
        }
    }

    static class ArrayExtensions
    {
        public static void PrintArray<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements)
        {
            foreach (var element in elements)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(element);
            }
        }
    }
}
```