# Add array to an array - one by one

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string, list

I would like to add arrays to a list or multidimensional array (not all at once...). But I dont really understand why this should be that hard.

Lets say I have this:

```
    string[] a = { "h", "b"};
    string[] b = { "c", "a", "i" };
    string[] c = { "out", "in", "file", "test" };

    ArrayList x = null;

    x.Add(a); //error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    x.Add(b);
    x.Add(c);
```

Can I use instead of the ArrayList maybe

```
string[,] x = null;
```

But there is no option to .Add

Lets say I have an unknown amount of string[]´s with an unknown size - how do I add them to a List/multidimensional array? And again: I would like to add these string[]´s one by one. Any ideas?

Comment: Just wondering, what is this `ArrayList x = null;`?

Comment: The error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", for future reference, means you forgot to initialize your object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting an [`NullReferenceException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx) because your list is not initialized:

```
string[] a = { "h", "b"};
string[] b = { "c", "a", "i" };
string[] c = { "out", "in", "file", "test" };

IList<string[]> x = new List<string[]>;

x.Add(a);
x.Add(b);
x.Add(c);
```

This assumes that you are constructing a 2-D structure. If you would like to "flatten" your arrays into a single list of strings, create a list, and use its `List.AddRange` method instead.

Comment: Hi thx, this is nice, but how can I iterate through this List?... I get only System.String[] as output

Comment: @miri Are you trying to print elements of the list directly? The answer at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8954141/335858) explains how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

you haven't made an instance of the ArrayList you want to store the string arrays in. Try adding

```
ArrayList x = new ArrayList();
x.Add(a);
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ArrayList x = null;
> x.Add(a);
> ```

That would work if:

1. You create an instance of `ArrayList`:

   ```
   ArrayList x = new ArrayList();
   ```

   all you were doing was to declare a local variable.
2. You are careful to separate `ArrayList.Add` from `ArrayList.AddRange`. The former adds a single object. In your case the first element (after the first `Add`) would be itself an array. To access the "h" would need `x[0][0]`. `AddRange` takes each passed collection element in term and adds it to the collection. Thus getting the "h" would be `x[0]` and "b" would be `x[1]`.

I think you want:

```
string[] a = { "h", "b"};
string[] b = { "c", "a", "i" };
string[] c = { "out", "in", "file", "test" };

ArrayList x = new ArrayList();

x.AddRange(a);
x.AddRange(b);
x.AddRange(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `null` essentially means "no object". Therefore when you write `x.Add(a)` you are trying to call the `Add` method on something that isn't there.

You need to *initialize* your list first, which puts something in the box labelled `x`:

```
ArrayList x = new ArrayList();
```

You can now call `x.add(a)` and your code will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `new` for ArrayList so you should do it like this:

```
ArrayList x = new ArrayList();
    x.AddRange(a);
    x.AddRange(b);
    x.AddRange(c);
```

You can't can't use array in `Add` method , you will not get any compile error but then while you will access the object you will get just `ToString` on type that means if you say:

```
string[] a = { "h", "b"};
    x.Add(a);
```

and then try to loop through the elements like:

```
foreach (var item in x)
     {
    Console.WriteLine(item);
     }
```

you will the result: `System.String[]` and I hope you don't want that, so you need to use `AddRange` method which takes an argument of type `ICollection`, so you say:

`x.AddRange(a);`

and if you do a loop on array list like:

```
 foreach (var item in x)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(item);
         }
```

you will get the output,

```
h 
b
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is:

```
List<List<string>> list = new List<List<string>>();

    list.Add(new List<string>(){
        "str1", "str2", "..."
    });
```

be sure to include: using System.Collections.Generic;